# Flutter : How to create a Radio Buttons inside Listview?

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-button, row, flutter-listview

- I'm trying to implement a code as design attached in pic
- but when I'm trying to press in any item of list (Radio btns not updated with new value)
- could someone help me to implement it as design attached

[image: design sample]

```
 var _oneValue = '';
  var timeSlot = [
    "١٢:٠٠ منتصف الليل",
    "١:٠٠ صباحا",......


  Row(
                                                            mainAxisAlignment:
                                                                MainAxisAlignment
                                                                    .spaceBetween,
                                                            children: [
                                                              Expanded(
                                                                child: Text(
                                                                  (timeSlot[i]),
                                                                  style: Typographies
                                                                      .largeBodyStyle(),
                                                                ),
                                                              ),
                                                              Radio(
                                                                  activeColor:
                                                                      ColorManager
                                                                          .black,
                                                                  value: timeSlot[i],
                                                                  groupValue:
                                                                      _oneValue,
                                                                  onChanged:
                                                                      (value) {
                                                                    setState(
                                                                        () {
                                                                      _oneValue =
                                                                          value!;
                                                                      print(
                                                                          _oneValue);
                                                                    });
                                                                  })
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
```

- try to switch between items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  List timeSlot = [
    {'label': 'Item1', 'value': 1},
    {'label': 'Item2', 'value': 2}
  ];
  int _oneValue = -1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        for (var item in timeSlot)
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  (item['label']),
                  // style: Typographies.largeBodyStyle(),
                ),
              ),
              Radio(
                  activeColor: Colors.blue,
                  value: item['value'],
                  groupValue: _oneValue,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _oneValue = value!;
                      print(_oneValue);
                    });
                  })
            ],
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but in radioListTile : radio btn beside the title I need to separate them as design

Comment: You could always customise the radio button using its shape property

Comment: @FlutterDeveloper I have updated the code using your snippet and without radioListTile.Switching works here. Check once.

Comment: still not working,
'''

Comment: which part not working? I see the the values getting updated in print statement

Comment: its inside a bottom sheet and it was not rendered, but I solved it and worked now.